# Android JSON parsing array inside another array without key

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm new on JSON and i have some problems with json array. I don't know how to parse that "genres" array. At the moment it only works as an object but don't look good.

I want that "genres" to show Drama,Musical instead of ["Drama","Musical"]

JSON:

```
    {
   "status_message":"Query was successful",
   "data":{
      "movie_count":25241,
      "movies":[
         {
            "id":25805,
            "title":"Rock Around the World",
            "year":1957,
            "genres":[
               "Biography",
               "Drama",
               "Music"
            ],
```

The parsing code:

```
    ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONObject data = object.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray movies = data.getJSONArray("movies");

        for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject details = movies.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = details.getString("title");
            int year = details.getInt("year");
            String genres = details.getString("genres");

            Film film = new Film(title, year, genres);

            films.add(film);

        }
```

App show like this [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU85C.jpg)

Comment: Your error is in this line `String genres = details.getString("genres");`
You should retreive genres just like you retreive `movies`, an `array`.
Like this `JSONArray genres = details.getJSONArray("genres");`

Comment: I know this but after this what i need to do? What i need to write to work on Film film = new Film?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the genres and how you want to display them.
If you want to show them as a simple sentence you might want to do something like this
`genres.joinToString()`, that way instead of ["genre1","genre2"] you'll get "genre1, genre2"

Comment: I want to display them normal. Instead of ["Drama","Music"] to be Drama,Music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a simple way :

```
String genres  = "[\"Drama\",\"Musical\"]";

genres = genres.replace("[", "");
genres = genres.replace("]", "");
genres = genres.replace("\"", "");

Log.i("MY_TAG",genres);  // Drama,Musical
```

test it and use it !